# ¿Cómo convertir un ARRAY_AGG a INT o STRING? en BigQuery

Tags: sql, array, string, google-bigquery

Tengo una query que me saca la medida de ciertos códigos de productos, una tabla tengo los códigos de productos y en otra tengo las dimensiones, hay códigos de productos que tienen las dimensiones repetidas por lo cual me repite el código del producto, esto lo solucione utilizando un **ARRAY_AGG** y un **LIMIT 1**, pero ahora necesito realizar unos cálculos con estas dimensiones de los productos tales como **IF(Alto >15, "Conveyable", "No Conveyable")** pero como lo tengo en un **ARRAY_AGG** me sale este error **No matching signature for operator > for argument types: ARRAY, INT64. Supported signature: ANY > ANY at [6:6]**

¿Saben si hay forma de convertir el único resultado del **ARRAY_AGG** a **INT** o **STRING** o alguna forma de obtener un solo registro en la consulta sin tener que usar el **ARRAY_AGG** y un **LIMIT 1**?

Anexo la query realizada hasta el momento:

```
SELECT
  DATE(US.FBM_CREATED_DATE) AS Fecha,
  US.FBM_USER_ID as Usuario,
  US.INVENTORY_ID as codigo,
  if(ARRAY_AGG(IFNULL(ML.ITE_LENGTH, 0) RESPECT NULLS LIMIT 1 )>15, "Conveyable" , "No Conveyable" ) AS Alto,
  if(ARRAY_AGG(IFNULL(ML.ITE_WIDTH, 0) RESPECT NULLS LIMIT 1)>15, "Conveyable" , "No Conveyable" ) AS Ancho,
  if(ARRAY_AGG(IFNULL(ML.ITE_HEIGHT, 0) RESPECT NULLS LIMIT 1)>15, "Conveyable" , "No Conveyable" ) AS Largo,

FROM
  `tabla1` as US,
  `tabla2` as ML
WHERE
  AND US.INVENTORY_ID=ML.INVENTORY_ID
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```